# Error: [$injector:undef] Provider 'myFactory' must return a value from $get factory method

Tags: angularjs

I am still a learner in Angular Js. I kept getting the above error when trying to customize an $http service.
My factory is:

```js
angular.module('starter')
.factory('myFactory', ['$http', function($http){


var myFactory = {};
var events = [];

myFactory.getAllEvents = function(){
  $http.get("js/auth.json").then(function(data){
  events = data.data;

})

return events;

}

}])
```

and my controller is

```js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.controller('myController', function(myFactory){
var self = this;

 self.evenlist = myFactory.getAllEvents();
 console.log(self.evenlist)
})
```

Many thanks as you help.

Comment: Hi, when are you define your factory? I mean, whether you create your factory first then controller?

Comment: Yes. i defined it first on a separate file called factory.js. Then i was trying to call it in the controller called controller.js

Comment: Hi, Do you define your factory and controller as per the above code?

Comment: Because, it may arise an issue. When you define your factory, you are using **angular.module('starter')**. It means you are asking to fetch a module with name 'starter' not to create a module.

Comment: In the second code (when defining controller) you are asking to create a new module with name **starter**. So, it may be in different modules.

Comment: So, try using, a single variable to represent your module. That will be better.